# Convert NSString to NSDate returns (null) value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have one Date in string format "`2013-03-19T19:00:50`" 
 
I am trying to convert it into `NSDate` using `NSDateFormatter`

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
NSLog(@"date in date format : %@",startDate);
```

but it is giving me null date

```
date in date format : (null)
```

What is the issue?

Comment: what's your actual need means output that is expecting ?

Comment: T is the time designator that precedes the time components of the representation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use :

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
```

You have time in 24 hour format, so `HH` is required. `hh` is used when time is in 12 hour format.

And `T` is required to be in single quote, T is not a part of date this is an added text on it.

Comment: thanks @Anoop . iI test it for multiple time and it is working.

Comment: just one question why we have to put 'T' instead of just T?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [date formatter patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns) `hh` means `Hour [1-12]` You want `Hour [0-23]` which is `HH`.

And any letters that are not date format patterns, or must not be interpreted in this way have to be put in between apostrophes.

use `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];`

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
NSLog(@"date in date format : %@",startDate);
```

Comment: Great it is working. why we have to put 'T' instead of just T ?